# How to open password protected ODT file using LibreOffice

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-a

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab A.  LibreOffice is installed and ODT file is loaded into document folder.  This file is password protected and I have the password.   So how do I open this file????

Comment: acejavelin:  This file was created with LibreWrite.  Have no problem  opening it in Linux  using any PC.   OpenDocument reader can't open it.  Asks for me to upload so they can look at it.  I won't do that, file has sensitive info.        LibreWrite when accessing it goes into a 10 sec loop and hangs.  Doesn't ask for a password...

Answer (score 2):

It should prompt you for the password when you attempt to open it, if not, try [OpenDocument Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.tomtasche.reader) available in the Play Store... if neither can open it, it is likely a corrupt file.